# ignoreResourceNotFound=true throwing FileNotFound exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class written like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:secrets.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Secrets {

    private String username;
    private String password;

}
```

I expect it to work properly, when `europe-secrets.yaml` file is present, meaning injecting values into `username` and `password` fields, and just do nothing when the file is not present. Right now it's throwing `FileNotFoundException` when the file is missing (and is working properly when the file is there, even when empty) and thus failing to initialize Spring context, which breaks my whole application. It seems like the `ignoreResourceNotFound = true` attribute is not working. What am I missing here?

this is `YamlPropertySourceFactory`:

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your YamlPropertySourceFactory. Adding the following property before the failing line will solve your problem:

```
factory.setResolutionMethod(YamlProcessor.ResolutionMethod.OVERRIDE_AND_IGNORE);
```